# Migrate SQLIte Data in to MySQL and manage/update the foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite, synchronization

I'm developing an Android application in which the data is stored in a SQLite database.

I have made sync with a MySQL database, in the web, to where I'm sending the data stored in the SQLite in the device.

The problem is that I don't know how to maintain the relations between tables, because the primary keys are going to be updated with AUTO_INCREMENT, and the foreign keys remain the same, breaking the relations between tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a full migration, don't use auto increment during migration - create tables with normal columns. Use ALTER TABLE to change the model after import.

For incremental sync, the easiest way I see is additional column in each MySQL table called sqlite_id and filled with original id. Then you can update references using UPDATE (with joins).

Alternatives involve temporary tables for storing data and an auxiliary table used for pairing. Tedious for bigger data model.

The approach I tend to use, if possible, is to avoid auto increment in such situations. I have usaully an auxiliary table with four columns like this: t_import(tablename, operationid, sqlite_id, mysqlid).
Process is the following:

1. Import the primary keys into t_import. Use operationid to separate parallel imports if needed.
2. Generate new keys for data tables and store them into t_import table. This can be combined with step one.
3. Import the actual data and use t_import for setting new primary keys and restore relations.

That should work for most scenarios I know about.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks or the help, you have given me some ideas.

I will try to add a id2 field to the tables that will store the same value as the primary key (_id)

When I send the information from SQLite to MySQL and the primary key is incremented I will have the id2 field with the original value of the primary key so that I can compare it with the foreign key of the other tables and update it.

Let’s see if it works.

Thanks

Comment: Just be careful to do proper transaction isolation, if multiple syncs could run concurrently.